# proguard rule: multiple same lib but different version

Tags: android, android-proguard

In my project, i have using `org.json.JSONObject` from Android's SDK.

And i have also using a third-party lib. the lib also using `org.json`, but the version is `org.json:json:20170516`

The third-party lib is [com.vdurmont:emoji-java:4.0.0](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java)

When i enable `minifyEnabled`, the build system will choose `org.json:json:20170516` to replace mine.

But they are different. And it occurs some problems.

How to make the build system don't replace the `org.json` of mine.

Comment: Did you define 'org.json:json' in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: No, this package is contained by Android's SDK.

Comment: Try to put it there to override the version

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you mean.

What i want to know is the rule of proguard. And make my module use the package of Android' SDK but the third-party lib use his.